# ag-grid renders on top of cell renderer

Tags: html, css, angular, ag-grid

I've tried just about everything I know to get my custom dropdown cell renderer to display as the topmost div in the agGrid example. I've played with z-index, positioning etc with no luck.  The only thing that did anything was going to one of the offending rows and deselecting the transform for that row, but then the row just disappears.  Any ideas would would be welcome,  Thanks in advance.

Here is a working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-hides-cellrenderer-5ryv9n

[Quick screenshot of issue when menu is within ag-grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShF8E.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution for me was to add `suppressRowTransform: true` to the grid options and make the rows and cells have `overflow: visible`

This was using ag-grid-react though.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution helped a lot! I was struggling for past week for this problem.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the solution. It really helps but there is another issue I have while adding this suppressRowTransform: true to grid option. which is, the hover state is not getting stopped for a row when we are selecting any value (which is populated away from the row) from the dropdown of a row. The row remains in the hover state (color changes) until and unless hovered again. This can be replicated even in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z7aogy. Kindly help me on the same to resolve it.

Answer (score 8):

I have also came across the exact same problem (with ag-grid-react though).

Here is a working solution I've implemented **following Frank Wallis's answer above**:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z7aogy

Why does this work?

1. The **cell renderer** has a higher `z-index` than the ag-grid (only when the menu is open) [therefore it also must have a `position`, other than 'static'] (see ColorCell.js)
2. The **ag-grid cell** style contains: `overflow: visible` (see style.css)
3. In gridOptions: `suppressRowTransform=true` (see Table.js)

**Note that this is not perfect.** When 2+ menus are open simultaneously, one hides the other. This of course can be solved by making sure that no more than 1 menu is open at any given moment (like a regular select element behaves).

Comment: Alas, it doesn't solve my problem, which is that I have a long list of values in a small grid, and the list is under the edge of the grid.  In ColorCell.js, try making it Array(30) instead of Array(3) and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

In ag-grid-react recent versions, in your column definitions you can simply add a property 'cellClass' as shown below and the content of that cell can overflow (Worked for me with a tooltip):-

```
  columnData = [
{
  headerName: 'Column Name',
  field: 'colId',
  width: 260,
  suppressRowTransform: true,
  cellClass: 'overflow-visible'}]
```

I have provided this answer in case it's helpful for someone new like me to find the place where to put the overflow: visible. (Based on the answers above)