# How to display custom element over ag grid element?

Tags: css, ag-grid

I have custom html for specific cell where im doing some logic. This is my html:

```
<span class="first-span" (mouseover)="mouseover(params)" (mouseout)="out()">
  {{params.valueFormatted ? params.valueFormatted : params.value}}
  <span class="second-span" *ngIf="show">
    {{toolTip}}</span>
</span>
```

And this is my css:

```
.first-span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.second-span {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    pointer-events: none;
    padding: 0 3px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

My setup in grid for that specific column:

```
 {
        field: 'itemAmount',
        headerName: 'Final Price',
        filter: 'text',
        type: 'decimal',
        cellRendererFramework: ToolTipComponent,
        tooltip: (params: any) => { return ''; }
      },
```

What i want to achive is to second span display as tooltip on ag grid. Above current cell on hover,but right now i can only display it in cell because. If i put my top for example -10px it will not be visible because of header of ag grid. Any suggestion how can i achive to display even over ag grid header. I tried to add z-index but its not working. I cant add basic tooltip because i have logic to wait few seconds and then call external service and then display my values in custom tooltip.

Comment: I'm not sure it's 100% what you need (hence comment not answer) - have you tried using the popupParent https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/context-menu/#popup-parent?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711705/ag-grid-renders-on-top-of-cell-renderer